# Classic window decoration in Office 2007

Tags: windows-vista, microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2007, themes

Is there any way to get Office 2007 programs to run with a default Windows title-bar and window decoration?

We are using Group Policy to force Windows to use the Windows Classic theme (no compositing manager, Windows 2000 style window decoration) and the Office windows really stick out and look non-standard. I realize this is a purely aesthetic concern, but you know how managers like aesthetics.

I am including a screenshot to clarify how Office sticks out from everything else.

Is there an easy way to force Office to use a standard title-bar and window decoration? Thank you.

[image: Example of window decorations]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately no.  Office 2007 and above use a different type of windows management (WFA application) vs the old type of Windows 9x window form.  We have tried many ways to get this to function like the old Old office products in our environment with no avail.